# Basic Electrification problems

Tags: electricity

I am reading the experiments about Electrification in Part I Chapter I in "A Treatise on Electricity & Magnetism". There are few experiments on Electrification by friction, induction and conduction described in the book.

### Description

The demonstration of the experiments can be shown below.

[image: Experiment demonstration]

#### By friction

Firstly, the glass ball is rubbed with a piece of resin, thus the glass ball is *vitreously* electrified.

#### By induction

Then the electrified glass ball is put inside a metallic vessel **without touching it** with a silk thread, and it is found to be *vitreously* charged outside the vessel. If the ball is taken outside the vessel, then there is no electrification found outside the vessel.

#### By conduction

Finally, the electrified vessel (by induction) touches another metallic body with a conduction wire, then the body is found to be *vitreously* electrified and there is no sign of electrification outside the vessel.

### Question

The description above is summarised from "A Treatise on Electricity & Magnetism". Now My question is:

At the final step, the charge is transferred from the electrified vessel to the metallic body. But the electrification of the vessel is because the "temporary" induction from the electrified glass ball. Then why the vessel is not electrified anymore? How is the glass ball electrified now?

(P.S. There are two types of electrifications: *vitreously* electrified and *resinously* electrified.)